# Html Images dont render in outlook email via Blat

Tags: html, email, html-email, blat

I trying to send the following HTML page as an email using the command line tool blat.

Email is sent as expected but, the images are not loaded in the email message.The email content looks like :

[image]

```
<html>  
      <body>

        <style>
          .img2{

          height: 800px;
          max-height: 700px;
          background-size: 100% 100%;

        }
        </style>


          <div class="container">
           <div class="row" >
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3" >
               <img class='img2' src="cid:image1.png"/>
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3">
                 <img class='img2' src='image2.png'>
              </div>

              </div>

            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                 <img class='img2' src="D:\reports\image3.png"/>
              </div>
               </div>  
         </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried using 'cid' before the source path but in that case web page itself does not load the images as the path is resolved incorrectly.

Blat command used : `blat "D:\reports\mail_send_2.html" -t example@domain.com -s "email subject" -embed "D:\reports\image1.png" -embed "D:\reports\image2.png" -embed "D:\reports\image3.png" -html`

Could some one help me out here . Thanks !

Comment: Have you viewed the source of the email to see if your cid matches?

Comment: @DavidP Thanks for your reply. I am seeing the images now. But the email format is not the same as html page . Does Blat utility not take CSS in to consideration ?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with Blat per se, but one thing you should know is that you shouldn't use classes in your HTML for email. Not all email clients recognize it. Instead you should mark each HTML element with a style="" tag, and explicitly set CSS attributes. Kind of a pain, but...

Comment: @DavidP . Thank you for the information. Yes. CSS wasn't working when I tried to use classes on Blat had to mention the style tag for each element.

Comment: I'm glad it works. I posted my previous comments as answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you viewed the source of the email to see if your cid matches?

In addition, one thing you should know is that you shouldn't use classes in your HTML for email. Not all email clients recognize it. Instead you should mark each HTML element with a style="" tag, and explicitly set CSS attributes. Kind of a pain, but...

Answer (score 1):

Placed the images in the same folder as the Html page and then using cid and embed together worked as expected.